# I can't create a custom UIView in xib in Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

[image]

[image]

Hi, I am having trouble displaying a UIView in the storyboard using Xib like the first (top) image. Before the most recent update, when I create a xib for a view, it displayed like this.

But after update, when I load a UIView into the storyboard, it shows an UIViewController in the storyboard(bottom image) instead of a UIView.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Select the View, on the Inspector, choose `Freeform`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the view on left panel and then in right panel (inspector) set simulated metrics from **inferred** to **freeform**.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for bringing that up. I've tried it as well. Is it possible to get rid of safe area like a general UIView and the home button ( -------- ) in the bottom?

Comment: @LearningiOS After changing the size from inferred to freeform, drag the view into whatever size you want and it will be gone.

Comment: @Simran, Even if I changed the size of the view, safe area and the home button sign are not removed.

Comment: Try shifting to some other view controller class and then come back to xib file.

Comment: @Simran, will try it. Thanks!